# How to add external library to the classpath in scala's interpreter?

Tags: scala, classpath, interpreter

I'm trying to reference some classes in the Scala Interpreter that were writen and compiled using Eclipse. Eclipse stores compiled Java byte code in a folder {workspace}/myProject/bin. Is there some command which will add this folder to the classpath used by the Scala Interpreter?

Maybe scala.bat should be edited or parameterized with some argument?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the -classpath or -cp flags when launching the interpreter:

```
scala -cp /path/to/classfiles
```

Answer (score 1):

You can edit scala.bat, or rather make a copy to leave the original unchanged.

You will probably want to use **call :add_cpath "..."** to add it, as is used somewhere in that batch file.